# Flutter text yellow underline

Tags: flutter, dart

Can anybody know what's wrong with my code cause i m getting a yellow underline text. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1p2pB.png)
Here is my code:

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(10, 100, 10, 460),
                child: RichText(
                  text: TextSpan(
                      style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style,
                      children: [
                        TextSpan(
                            text: "asdad",
                            style:
                                TextStyle(color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6)))
                      ]),
                )),
            const TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'What s your name?', border: OutlineInputBorder()),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I've tried to wrap with MaterialApp, not working

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a MaterialApp and you should not have everything in only one widget like this.

DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style is not able to reach the MaterialApp to get the default text style. It has to be in another widget class (or a Builder widget) so that the context lets you reach the MaterialApp.

Comment: Thx, it's working after i remove DefaultTextStyle.of(context)

Comment: @Marian separate the widget instead of removing it,